Packet checksum is negative after resolving DNS
I am trying to add DNS over HTTPS to a VPN app. for project reference VPN-Example. In this project I am only trying to add dns queries to be going over DNS over HTTPS(DoH) instead of simple DNS queries. I am able to do so and receive the response for DoH. The problem i end up facing is that when I update the packet I am missing something or not doing something right which is leading to checksum calculation errors. I am new to networking and am unable to debug this issue.
in VPN VPNRunnable's Run method i added following code to find the DNS query packets and then resolve DNS with DoH.
private static class VPNRunnable implements Runnable {
//...
@Override
public void run() {
//...
    if (packet.isDNSQuery()) {
        String domain = packet.getDomainName();
        Result resolvedResult = resolveDomainOverDoH(domain);
        Log.i(TAG, "DNS Packet Before: " + packet.toString());
        if (resolvedResult != null && !Objects.requireNonNull(resolvedResult.getAnswer()).isEmpty()) {
            Packet dnsResponsePacket = buildDNSResponse(packet, resolvedResult);
            if (dnsResponsePacket != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "DNS Packet After: " + dnsResponsePacket.toString());

                networkToDeviceQueue.offer(dnsResponsePacket.toByteBuffer());
                Log.i(TAG, "DNS response created for domain: " + domain);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create DNS response for domain: " + domain);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to resolve DNS query for domain: " + domain);
        }
    } else if (packet.isUDP()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "read udp" + readBytes); // Logs UDP read operation
        deviceToNetworkUDPQueue.offer(packet); // Adds packet to UDP queue
    } //...

In the above code I am able to receive the proper DNS over HTTPS response via

data class Result(
    @SerializedName("Status") val status: Int,
    @SerializedName("TC") val tc: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("RD") val rd: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("RA") val ra: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("AD") val ad: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("CD") val cd: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("Question") val question: List<Question>?,
    @SerializedName("Answer") val answer: List<Answer>?,
    @SerializedName("Authority") val authority: List<Authority>?,
    @SerializedName("edns_client_subnet") val ednsClientSubnet: String?
)
data class Question(
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("type") val type: Int
)

data class Answer(
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("type") val type: Int,
    @SerializedName("TTL") val ttl: Int,
    @SerializedName("Expires") val expires: String,
    @SerializedName("data") val data: String
)

data class Authority(
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("type") val type: Int,
    @SerializedName("TTL") val ttl: Int,
    @SerializedName("Expires") val expires: String,
    @SerializedName("data") val data: String
)

and dns over HTTPs lookup code:

    // Perform a synchronous DNS lookup
    fun lookup(domain: String, type: Int): Result? {
        for (resolver in resolvers) {
            val url = "${resolver.url}?name=$domain&type=$type"
            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .apply {
                    if (resolver.method == Method.POST) post(RequestBody.create(null, ByteArray(0)))
                }
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/dns-json")
                .build()

            try {
                val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body?.let { responseBody ->
                        return gson.fromJson(responseBody.string(), Result::class.java)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // Log or handle exception
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return null
    }

The problem starts after i try to use this code to update the packet and send it back to the device. My packet updation code after i pass it DNS response Result:

    public static Packet buildDNSResponse(Packet queryPacket, Result responseInfo) {
        try {
            // Create a new response packet based on the query packet
            ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1500); // Allocate a large enough buffer
            responseBuffer.put(queryPacket.backingBuffer.array(), 0, queryPacket.backingBuffer.limit());
            responseBuffer.clear();

            Packet responsePacket = new Packet(responseBuffer);

            // Swap source and destination IP addresses
            byte[] tempIp = responsePacket.ip4Header.sourceAddress.getAddress();
            responsePacket.ip4Header.sourceAddress = responsePacket.ip4Header.destinationAddress;
            responsePacket.ip4Header.destinationAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(tempIp);

            // Swap source and destination ports
            int tempPort = responsePacket.udpHeader.sourcePort;
            responsePacket.udpHeader.sourcePort = responsePacket.udpHeader.destinationPort;
            responsePacket.udpHeader.destinationPort = tempPort;

            // Modify DNS header
            int dnsStart = Packet.IP4_HEADER_SIZE + Packet.UDP_HEADER_SIZE;
            responsePacket.backingBuffer.putShort(dnsStart + 2, (short) 0x8180); // DNS flags: Standard query response, No error
            responsePacket.backingBuffer.putShort(dnsStart + 6, (short) responseInfo.getAnswer().size()); // Answer RRs

            // Find the end of the question section
            int questionEnd = findQuestionEnd(responsePacket.backingBuffer, dnsStart);

            // Add answer section
            int answerStart = questionEnd;
            for (Answer answer : responseInfo.getAnswer()) {
                answerStart = addAnswerRecord(responsePacket.backingBuffer, answerStart, answer);
            }

            // Update packet length
            int totalLength = answerStart;
            responsePacket.ip4Header.totalLength = totalLength;
            responsePacket.backingBuffer.putShort(2, (short) totalLength);

            // Update UDP length
            int udpLength = totalLength - Packet.IP4_HEADER_SIZE;
            responsePacket.udpHeader.length = udpLength;
            responsePacket.backingBuffer.putShort(Packet.IP4_HEADER_SIZE + 4, (short) udpLength);

            // Recalculate checksums
            responsePacket.updateIP4Checksum();

            // Adjust the limit of the backing buffer
            responsePacket.backingBuffer.limit(totalLength);

            return responsePacket;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error building DNS response", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static int findQuestionEnd(ByteBuffer buffer, int dnsStart) {
        int position = dnsStart + 12; // Start after DNS header
        while (buffer.get(position) != 0) {
            position += buffer.get(position) + 1;
        }
        return position + 5; // +1 for null byte, +4 for QTYPE and QCLASS
    }

    private static int addAnswerRecord(ByteBuffer buffer, int start, Answer answer) throws UnknownHostException {
        buffer.putShort(start, (short) 0xC00C); // Pointer to question name
        buffer.putShort(start + 2, (short) answer.getType());
        buffer.putShort(start + 4, (short) 1); // CLASS IN
        buffer.putInt(start + 6, answer.getTtl());

        byte[] rdata = parseRDATA(answer.getType(), answer.getData());
        buffer.putShort(start + 10, (short) rdata.length);
        buffer.position(start + 12);
        buffer.put(rdata);

        return start + 12 + rdata.length;
    }

    private static byte[] parseRDATA(int type, String data) throws UnknownHostException {
        switch (type) {
            case 1: // A record
                return InetAddress.getByName(data).getAddress();
            case 28: // AAAA record
                return InetAddress.getByName(data).getAddress();
            case 5: // CNAME record
            case 16: // TXT record
            default:
                return data.getBytes();
        }
    }

So the resulting packet from buildDNSResponse() is not correct and I am unsure where does the problem lie.

Bear in mind that all numeric types in Java are signed. I you want the checksum to 'look positive' you will have to unsign it
